# Generate Excel 2010 Pivot Table from Java

Tags: java, excel, pivot-table

Does anyone know sever side library (free or not - it doesn't matter) which can generate pivot tables in excel 2010 format.

POI can't do it.

Now I'm evaluating SmartXLS but it uses Excel 2007 format.  I need couple feature from Excel 2010 - like data field sorting, default pivot table template and etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for this, although SmartXLS or POI might support it by now, they will always run behind with new developments in Excel. If you always want to be able to script the latest features in Excel, you'll be better off coding in .net (or PowerShell, VBScript, VBA)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question suggests to use [X4J](https://github.com/jbaliuka/x4j-analytic), which seems promising but I have not tried it myself.

[Java open source library to generate pivot table out of excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850120/java-open-source-library-to-generate-pivot-table-out-of-excel)