# Java open source library to generate pivot table out of excel

Tags: excel, open-source, pivot-table, java

Given an excel file I want to generate a pivot table programmatically. I have heard of Aspose.Cells but it is paid version. Can someone suggest some open source libraries similar to Aspose.Cells or atleast any tutorial link where I can get some help to generate pivot table programmatically.

Comment: Is there any new info on this issue?  I'd like to create xlsx reports in java.  Is there an api for that?

Answer (score 3):

Please try https://github.com/jbaliuka/x4j-analytic, it is open source and it is designed for pivot reports with huge details sheet.

There are several other open source libraries to achieve the same thing but we developed this library to workaround performance issues, we use temp file to avoid  unreasonable memory consumption and write XML to stream as raw bytes to avoid overhead caused by XML API.

See samples https://github.com/jbaliuka/x4j-analytic/blob/master/samples/src/test/java/x4j/samples/X4JEngineTest.java, it needs XLSX template, XML descriptor and several lines of code to implement basic pivot report.